# SQL syntax error in case statement inside sum function

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

Below is my code:

```
SELECT HOUR(asl.Start_Time) AS [Hour],
       t.team_name,
       SUM( CASE WHEN asl.Working = 1 
                 THEN asl.Duration_Seconds 
                 ELSE 0 END) 
           AS TotalSeconds
FROM (Agents 
         INNER JOIN Teams AS t 
         ON Agents.team_no = Teams.team_no)
      INNER JOIN AgentStateLogs AS asl 
      ON Agents.agent_no = asl.Agent_No
GROUP BY t.team_name, HOUR(asl.Start_Time);
```

The problem is that it is saying there is a missing operator in the statement:

```
SUM( CASE WHEN asl.Working = 1 
          THEN asl.Duration_Seconds 
          ELSE 0 END) 
    AS TotalSeconds
```

Ive been trying to find it and I just cant see where the error lies. Can anyone shed some light on this for me? This code is being done in MS Access 2013.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @ta: d'oh.... *hangs head in shame...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN asl.Working = 1 
THEN asl.Duration_Seconds 
ELSE 0 END
```

Translated to JET, this becomes

```
IIf(asl.Working = 1, asl.Duration_Seconds, 0)
```

Search for *immediate if* in [the manual](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966377.aspx) for more information.